# Ninject.MVC3. Bootstrapper.Initialize throws "Sequence contains no elements"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

this question is not new, but my problem seems to have a different root than those I have seen so far.

I have a solution containing several projects: two of them are C# MVC4. I installed Ninject.MVC3 Nuget package on both and I am using the NinjectWebCommon class in App_Start folder approach (https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application).

Versions:

1. Ninject 3.2.2.0
2. Ninject.MVC3 3.2.1.0
3. Ninject.Web.Common 3.2.3.0
4. Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost 3.2.3.0
5. WebActivator 2.0.5

NinjectWebCommon.cs of the first project:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;
using S1.MVC.Filters.CentralAutenticacao.Business;
using S1.MVC.Filters.Error;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(S1.CRM.Eventos.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(S1.CRM.Eventos.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace S1.CRM.Eventos.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.BindFilter<FiltroCentralAutenticacao>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
            kernel.BindFilter<GenericErro>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
        }        
    }
}
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs of the second project:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;
using S1.MVC.Filters.CentralAutenticacao.Business;
using S1.MVC.Filters.Error;

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(S1.CRM.Crud.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(S1.CRM.Crud.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace S1.CRM.Crud.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.BindFilter<FiltroCentralAutenticacao>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
            kernel.BindFilter<GenericErro>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
        }        
    }
}
```

Here is the global.asax file of the first project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace S1.CRM.Eventos
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

and of the second one:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace S1.CRM.Crud
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run any of the two projects, I get an InvalidOperationException saying "Sequence contains no elements" when calling

```
bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
```

Stacktrace:

```
in System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
in Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.Start()
in Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.<Initialize>b__0(INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin c)
in Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map[T](IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action)
in Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback)
in S1.CRM.Eventos.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() in d:\git-paulo\S1.CRM\S1.CRM.Eventos\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:line 30
```

Some people had this problem when they make global.asax derive from NinjectHttpApplication and also use NinjectWebCommon class, or when they rename assemblies ([Ninject + MVC3 = InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160946/ninject-mvc3-invalidoperationexception-sequence-contains-no-elements)). That's not my case.

Other guy got this error when two projects in the same solution where using WebActivator to initialize Ninject ([Ninject for Web Site and Api - Sequence contains no elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138503/ninject-for-web-site-and-api-sequence-contains-no-elements)). So I tried to unload one of the projects, but still kept getting the error.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Can you also post which exact method inside Ninject throws this exception (you might also have to check the innerexceptions as well)?

Comment: I added the stacktrace of the exception. There is no inner exception. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed there was another project using WebActivator in the solution: a class library referenced by one of the MVC projects. I didn't suspect of it, because it doesn't make any sense to have WebActivator in there.

Answer (score 2):

> This error also occurs if there is are **Exists 2 code files** references 
>   +**NinjectWebCommon.cs** (located usually in App_Start folder) in the solution.
>
> If there are multiple Initialize() method exist this also results error
>   similar to “**Sequence contains no elements**”

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the “Sequence contains no elements” due to my references. Please check your references. If there is a reference to another project which contains Ninject Infrastructure directory also causes the error. If you delete it problem may be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me for a different reason - I had two Bootstrapper instances each trying to initialise a Ninject kernel.

That is to say, I had the typical NinjectWebCommon code in two places because when I updated Ninject (with nuget), the update process inserted a new code file in the default place. Originally I had moved the typical NinjectWebCommon code elsewhere.